# How to set a parameter in php, and how to get its value?

Tags: php, hyperlink

How can I see the Edit Mode page is the link is written like:

`<small><i><a href="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>?editz=1">Edit Mode</a></i></small>`

In the above case, if I click the Edit Mode button in the homepage, does it mean editz will be assigned a value as 1?
Another question is if I have three php files a.php, b.php and c.php, which all check isset($editz), how can I redirect the page to a.php, rather than file b or c if I click the Edit Mode button?

Sorry maybe my question is too simple a naive, but I am a newbie to php, it is my first time tough php code. Please be kind to share some light:)

Comment: We can't really say for sure without the underlying code, but with that link the value of `$_GET['editz']` will be `1`.

Comment: @Samsquanch You mean if I do isset($editz), the statement will be TRUE, right?

Comment: no, but if you do `isset($_GET['editz'])` that should return `true`.

Comment: Glad I could help, even though I have no idea what the question was.

Comment: He forgot doing `$editz = $_GET['editz']`

Comment: @Samsquanch Does it mean every time we want to get the value from the parameter, the only way is $_GET['param_name'], rather than using the dollar sign $param_name to get the value?

Comment: You can use what @JiFus said above: `$editz = $_GET['editz']` and then just use `$editz` instead.

Comment: @JiFus Thanks! But where should I put this assignment, in the file where editz is used? Or in the index.php?

Comment: Just make a hyperlink link like so: `<a href="a.php?editz=1">Edit page</a>` Now at your a.php (the file you wanted to edit) look for the get variable, like: `if (isset($_GET['editz']) && $_GET['editz'] == 1) { //do your editing stuff }`

Comment: @JiFus Thanks JiFus for your kindly reply. What if my parameter is like $param1[$parame2], how can I do $_GET['param_name'] to assign the value to $param1[$param2]?

Comment: If you mean $param1 is an array, you can assign as follows: `$param1[$parame2] = $_GET['param_name'];` More about arrays [here](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give some sort of answer to this, spanning from the comments:

Anything following a `?` in a URL is a query string, and the parameters (each separated by `&`) can be accessed with the `$_GET['parameter_name']` function. In this case, `$_GET['editz']` was needed.